# Rails find all through belongs_to and HABTM searchkick / Elasticsearch with search_data associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, elasticsearch, belongs-to, searchkick

I have `category_id` and I am trying to find all the `sub_category`s (records) that associated with Post. I am using searchkick `search_data` that does not work:

```
def search_data
    attributes.merge (
        category_id: sub_category(&:category_id)
    )
end
```

Search method:

```
Post.search search_query,
    where: search_options
```

If the search params is `search_options[:category_id] = 3` the result is empty.

Models:

```
Post < ActiveRecord
   belongs_to :sub_category

Category < ActiveRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :sub_categories

SubCategory < ActiveRecord
   has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
```

But it work if I find in advance the `categories`  like so:

```
  category = Category.find( 3 )
  search_options[:category_id] = category.sub_categories.pluck(:id)
```

Why `search_data` not work as expected? (without the workaround above)

How can I make it work?